# Android test cases robolectric Shadowlooper idle VS idleFor

Tags: android, robolectric, android-looper, android-junit, mainlooper

**using robolectric version 4.5.1**

What is the difference between

```
 shadowOf(getMainLooper()).idleFor(1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

and

```
 shadowOf(getMainLooper()).idle();
```

shadowOf(getMainLooper()).idle(); is **causing my test case to fail** giving following exception message

```
Main looper has queued unexecuted runnables. This might be the cause of the test 
failure. You might need a shadowOf(getMainLooper()).idle() call.
java.lang.Exception: Main looper has queued unexecuted runnables. This might be the cause of the test failure. You might need a shadowOf(getMainLooper()).idle() call.
at org.robolectric.android.internal.AndroidTestEnvironment.checkStateAfterTestFailure(AndroidTestEnvironment.java:502)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$HelperTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:581)
at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner$2.lambda$evaluate$0(SandboxTestRunner.java:278)
at org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.Sandbox.lambda$runOnMainThread$0(Sandbox.java:89)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

**But shadowOf(getMainLooper()).idleFor(1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS); this works fine how?**

as documentation idleFor Advances the system clock by the given time, then executes all posted tasks scheduled before or at the given time. What it means **Advances the system clock**? **How my test is getting passed on using idleFor() instead of idle()**

Answer (score 0):

We can find both functions in [ShadowPausedLooper](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/blob/fda5c14500b9511788065e94f6502d40f93f2f88/shadows/framework/src/main/java/org/robolectric/shadows/ShadowPausedLooper.java#L91):

```
  @Override
  public void idle() {
    executeOnLooper(new IdlingRunnable());
  }

  @Override
  public void idleFor(long time, TimeUnit timeUnit) {
    long endingTimeMs = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + timeUnit.toMillis(time);
    long nextScheduledTimeMs = getNextScheduledTaskTime().toMillis();
    while (nextScheduledTimeMs != 0 && nextScheduledTimeMs <= endingTimeMs) {
      SystemClock.setCurrentTimeMillis(nextScheduledTimeMs);
      idle();
      nextScheduledTimeMs = getNextScheduledTaskTime().toMillis();
    }
    SystemClock.setCurrentTimeMillis(endingTimeMs);
    // the last SystemClock update might have added new tasks to the main looper via Choreographer
    // so idle once more.
    idle();
  }
```

`idle()` will only run immediate `Runnables` where `idleFor()` will check for next scheduled task and if it exists move system time
`SystemClock.setCurrentTimeMillis(nextScheduledTimeMs);`

We can check [ShadowPausedMessageQueue](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/blob/fda5c14500b9511788065e94f6502d40f93f2f88/shadows/framework/src/main/java/org/robolectric/shadows/ShadowPausedMessageQueue.java#L36) for `getNextScheduledTaskTime()`

```
  Duration getNextScheduledTaskTime() {
    Message next = peekNextExecutableMessage();

    if (next == null) {
      return Duration.ZERO;
    }
    return Duration.ofMillis(convertWhenToScheduledTime(shadowOfMsg(next).getWhen()));
  }
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.